# IONIC 2 not displaying *ngFor iterate data in UI

Tags: json, angular, ionic2

**Problem Statement**

I am calling an external JSON API data into my IONIC2 app and trying to display the data in an ion-item. I am able to consume the JSON data in my app but not able to display it.

Please find my code in the below:

*pnr_status.html:*

```
 <ion-card>
 <ion-card-header color="primary">
  PNR STATUS  
 </ion-card-header>

 <ion-list>
 <ion-item *ngFor="let res of pnrResult.passengers">
 <ion-label>
    Item Label
 </ion-label>
 <div item-content>
     Item {{res.current_status}}    
 </div>
 </ion-item>
 </ion-list>    
 </ion-card>
```

*pnr_status.ts:*

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import {Http} from '@angular/http';
import { RailwayServiceProvider } from '../../providers/railway-service/railway-service';
import 'rxjs/Rx';
/**
* Generated class for the PnrStatusPage page.
*
* See http://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#navigation for more info
* on Ionic pages and navigation.
*/
@IonicPage()

@Component({
selector: 'page-pnr-status',
templateUrl: 'pnr-status.html',
})
export class PnrStatusPage {




 pnrResult = [];

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, public http: Http,
  private railwayService:RailwayServiceProvider) {
   this.get_pnr_status();
   alert(this.pnrResult);
  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log('ionViewDidLoad PnrStatusPage');

  }

get_pnr_status(){


this.railwayService.getMessage().subscribe(data=>{this.pnrResult=data});


}

}
```

*Provider: railway-services.ts*

```
 import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/do'
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch'
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable'
/*
  Generated class for the RailwayServiceProvider provider.

  See https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/dependency-injection.html
  for more info on providers and Angular DI.
*/
@Injectable()
export class RailwayServiceProvider {

 private url:string=" JSON API URL";

  constructor(private http: Http) {
    console.log('Hello RailwayServiceProvider Provider');
  }

getMessage(){

 return this.http.get(this.url)
 .do(this.logResponse)
 .map(this.extractData)
 .catch(this.catchError)
}

//Error Method...........................
private catchError(error : Response | any){
   console.log(error); 
   return Observable.throw(error.json().error || "Server Error!")
}

//Logout from resonse...........
private logResponse(res:Response)
{
  console.log(res);
}

//extract data from response.....
private extractData(res:Response){

  return res.json;
}

}
```

> JSON RESPONSE
>
> {"doj": "1-8-2017", "train_start_date": null, "train_name": "12841",
>   "boarding_point": {"name": null, "code": "HWH"}, "pnr": "6704386702",
>   "passengers": [{"current_status": "CNF/12", "booking_status":
>   "CNF/12/TQ", "coach_position": 0, "no": 1}], "debit": 3,
>   "total_passengers": 1, "class": "SL", "journey_class": {"name":
>   "SLEEPER CLASS", "code": "SL"}, "chart_prepared": true,
>   "from_station": {"name": "HOWRAH JN", "code": "HWH"}, "to_station":
>   {"name": "CHENNAI CENTRAL", "code": "MAS"}, "reservation_upto":
>   {"name": "CHENNAI CENTRAL", "code": "MAS"}, "response_code": 200,
>   "train_num": "12841", "train": {"name": "COROMANDAL EXP", "number":
>   "12841"}}

*Console Log:*

[image]

I am new to IONIC2. So any type help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: is there an error?

Comment: No there is no error .

Comment: is a json array or just json , i think it is just json object

Comment: I think the line `return res.json;` has to be `return res.json();`

Comment: Yes its just a JSON response

Comment: ngFor works only for json array ? not for plain objects for plain objects just use `object?.property`

Comment: @RahulSingh can you please share some reference docs on the same.. As I am new to Ionic2, it will be helpful for me.

Comment: @Nemo i have not worked on ionic i have on Angular though. you can check my [page](https://rahulrsingh09.github.io/AngularConcepts) if it helps in any manner

Comment: declare  `pnrResult` like this `pnrResult: any;`

Comment: console.log and print what is inside this.pnrResult